# Google Maps is grey

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps in a mobile application using html and javascript. When the I load the map I am only able to see 5% of the map in the upper left corner. 95% of the div container is grey.
When I want to check the div with Firebug the whole map is loaded suddenly.
What can that be? 
I tried already several Stackoverflow threads but no solution worked for me.
Thank you.

Code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile...>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile...></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile...></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js">       </script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 700px;"></div>

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 10,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                                
});
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
});
```

When I use div attributes measured in % or em it doesnt work at all.

Comment: need to see the code... or even better a sandboxed version.

Comment: Sounds like the map is initialized before the container element has properly sized. `google.maps.event.trigger(map 'resize')` where `map` is your map.

Comment: Have you specified a size for the div container holding the map, if so, which entity did you use, px, em, %?

Comment: I have to work with px attribute since em and % dont work at all yet. google.maps.event.trigger(map 'resize'); works at least in Firefoxconsole but not in my code so far.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try calling the resize method on document ready too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is $(document).ready(function()?
When I type google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); in firefox console it actually works.

Comment: [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is one of the ways to run code after the page has loaded using jQuery. It will run after all your css and script files have been loaded, but if you've got other JS which changes the layout of the page, it will still be too early and you'll need to call resize after changing the layout.

Comment: I basically used this right now:
$('#click-test').click(function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
 });
It works now but I don't know if it is just luck.

Answer (score 21):

Check your mapOptions whether its center or other properties are correct. In my occasion, center property was uninterpretable by google map; although the page was totally errorless in terms of css and jsp, it showed me just grey map all the time.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: Brilliant!!! Just went here: https://www.latlong.net/ and realised I was putting them in the wrong order :D

Answer (score 4):

In my case my map wasn't loading because I didn't set a `zoom` option.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 10, // Forgot to set this prop
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25)                               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, just calling `map.refresh()` fixed this issue. I am using Gmaps.

Comment: "map.refresh() is not a function"

Comment: It should be, assuming you named the variable "map" just like the OP did.

Comment: This is not referenced in the Google Maps docs, so it must have been an older API version. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because the mapTypeId was NULL.

Try:

```
map.setMapTypeId("roadmap");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had missed to provide the Longitude which came from an external API. Once the API was fixed to include Longitude, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question using [angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890815/google-maps-grey-box-on-ngif)
I could only get the map to refresh / recreate by using a `setTimeout` **AND** a `setZoom` (even though the level is the same)

```
// set timeout.
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("attempting refresh");
    google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, "resize");
    this.map.setZoom(8);
},
100);
```

**[Working Plunker Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/CZTnGw?p=preview)**

What's fascinating about the refresh, is that it moves the map the second time it is displayed.
Google maps is clearly not [bug free](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support).