# Google Maps Grey Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-chrome

So, what I have here is something similar to the grey maps, except here I see all the buttons. Everything looks 100% normal except the Map tiles. They're all grey! So what happens, and this is odd, is that it loads nicley at zoom 8 then zooms in to max and then Grey Tiles me. And now for the code:

```
 <style>

     html, body, #map-canvas {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       width: 100%;
     }


   </style>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBN5n7Q_LBTusrg4ae_vFtDWq22SZg5orU&sensor=false"></script>
   <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
     mapOptions);
 var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://pasteht.ml/pr7Xm',
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    map: map
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
```

Comment: Also odd, this code was scavenged from a previously working GMaps system.

Comment: Make sure you've set a height and width on your map element, preferably with CSS.

Comment: See also all the other questions on SO related to this, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525749/google-maps-is-grey?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<coordinates/>` for the Placemark are not valid.

In KML the order has to be `longitude, latitude` (with the reverse order the latitude will be set to `-122.419416`, which is an invalid value for a latitude...the valid range is approximately `-85 to 85`)

Comment: Oh, what an Idiot I am!

Comment: The map shows grey if the 'center' parameter of mapOptions is invalid. You don't get any hint from Google here (console).