# show the map not clear and centered, using multiple polylines and marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show Google maps with complex polyline and markers through value passed from db.
Everything work fine, but the maps come out grey and is not centered
I tried different solutions but all gave me same problem.
Below my Js code and the html call.
Any idea why i got this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.2041028, 28.047305100000017);
        var mapOpt = {
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 3,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-210'), mapOpt);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        var tripPlanCoordinates = [];
        var locations = [
            ["Johannesburg", -26.2041028, 28.047305100000017, 1],
            ["Mpumalanga", -25.565336, 30.52790959999993, 2],
            ["Kruger Park", -24.7562879, 31.81070790000001, 3],
            ["Città del Capo", -33.9248685, 18.424055299999964, 4],
            ["Mahé", -4.6826693, 55.48039599999993, 5],
        ];
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            tripPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://localhost/images/markers/1-default.png',
                title: "'" + locations[i][0] + "'"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    console.log("#stage_" + i);
                    window.location.href = "#stage_" + i;
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
        var tripPlan = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: tripPlanCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#B12138',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        tripPlan.setMap(map);
    }

    function loadMapScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadMapScript();
    }); 
    </script>
    <div id="map-210" style="width:100%; height:380px;"></div>
```

Comment: Is that your complete HTML/CSS? If so, your map doesn't have a size.

Comment: [The posted code "works" for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zkj0sgp7/).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, including a clear description of the problem.

Comment: if you mean an id yes there is. Is the map-210(the number is the id of the page)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.2041028, 28.047305100000017);
        var mapOpt = {
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 3,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-210'), mapOpt);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        var tripPlanCoordinates = [];
        var locations = [
            ["Johannesburg", -26.2041028, 28.047305100000017, 1],
            ["Mpumalanga", -25.565336, 30.52790959999993, 2],
            ["Kruger Park", -24.7562879, 31.81070790000001, 3],
            ["Città del Capo", -33.9248685, 18.424055299999964, 4],
            ["Mahé", -4.6826693, 55.48039599999993, 5],
        ];
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            tripPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://localhost/images/markers/1-default.png',
                title: "'" + locations[i][0] + "'"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    console.log("#stage_" + i);
                    window.location.href = "#stage_" + i;
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
        var tripPlan = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: tripPlanCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#B12138',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        tripPlan.setMap(map);
    }

    function loadMapScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadMapScript();
    }); 
    </script>
    <div id="map-210" style="width:100%; height:380px;"></div>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, but is not working on me see this
www.tinkywinky.it/index.php?name=Liste&op=liste_detail&lista_id=210&id_category=39 then click the first tab "Il Viaggio" you will see what i mean
And the strange think is that i have no error.

Comment: I can't find the tab

Comment: [link]http://www.tinkywinky.it/index.php?name=Liste&op=liste_detail&lista_id=210&id_category=39[/link]
try now

Comment: try adding `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` when the div for the tab is visible. Similar problems : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525749/google-maps-is-grey