# google maps grey box on *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript

I have a component.

```
@Component({
    selector: "panda-map",
    template: `
        <div class="map" [style.height.px]="height">
        </div>
    `
})
export class PandaMapComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() height: string = "400";
    @Input() scroll: boolean = false;
    map: google.maps.Map;

    constructor(
        private readonly element: ElementRef,
        private readonly logger: NGXLogger) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const div = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector("div");
        if (this.map)
            return;

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
            div,
            {
                zoom: 8,
                center: { lat: -26.1714402, lng: 28.0050053 },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: this.scroll
            });
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, "resize");
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "idle", function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, "resize");
        });
    }
}
```

The map is shown on a parent component like this:

```
<div class="pull-left shadow-panel map" *ngIf="address">
   <div>
      <panda-map [height]="400">
      </panda-map>
   </div>
</div>
```

The address is changed periodically.

> The first time the map is created, it works perfectly. If the address is set to null, and then a new value is assigned to address the map just shows a grey box.

As you can see I have tried various refresh mechanisms, none of which seem to refresh the map correctly.

**[Complete Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R3Ut0W?p=preview)**

The first time you click show/hide, the map is drawn.
After that it's just a grey box.

Comment: Can you provide a working example on codepen or similar?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: @fjc, I have added a plunker.

Comment: I have tested this with my API key present, no difference. I am using Chrome on windows 10 (all updated)

Comment: It’s not a duplicate from what I can see. I have tried the refresh (in the plunked) and it doesn’t help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular directive ***ngIf** removes the tag in your DOM. But your component executes ngOnInit just one time. So your map is not reinit correctly.

You can use **[style.display]** instead ***ngIf**

```
  <div class="sh" [style.display]="address ? 'none' : 'block'">
    <panda-map ></panda-map>
  </div>
```

(I tried on your plunker and it's working right)

Comment: NgOnInit executes every time the address changes? If I try using [hidden]=“!address” I have the same issue. I want to know how to reinitialise the map - not make it a singleton. I suspect I will have other issues when there are multiple maps on the same SPA app.

Comment: Did you try my code fixing?