# Google map turns grey after page reload

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following javascript in order to get the latitude and longitude by clicking a point on a google map.
When I visit the page, initially the map loads and all works fine in terms of clicking on it and getting the coordinates, but after reloading the page the map turns grey and no errors show up inside the web browser console.
Any idea what I might have wrong and how to fix this issue?

```js
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookie = document.cookie;
        var prefix = name + "=";
        var begin = cookie.indexOf("; " + prefix);
        if (begin == -1) {
            begin = cookie.indexOf(prefix);
            if (begin != 0) return null;
        } else {
            begin += 2;
            var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
            if (end == -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
        }
        return unescape(cookie.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    }
    function initialize() {
        var myCookie = getCookie("other_lat_lng");

        if (myCookie == null) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713956, -74.006653);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 9,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                draggable: true,
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Your location"
            });
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                map: map,
                radius: 24140,    // 15 miles in metres
                fillColor: '#08aa23'
            });
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
                document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
                getAddress(event.latLng);
                var cookie_val = ('other_lat_lng', event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng())
                document.cookie = "other_lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
                marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
                getAddress(event.latLng);
                var cookie_val = ('other_lat_lng', event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng())
                document.cookie = "other_lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
            });

        } else {
            array = myCookie.split(',');
            var split_1 = array[0];
            var split_2 = array[1];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(split_1, split_2);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 9,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                draggable: true,
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Your location"
            });
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                map: map,
                radius: 24140,    // 15 miles in metres
                fillColor: '#08aa23'
            });
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
                document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
                getAddress(event.latLng);
                var cookie_val = ('other_lat_lng', event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng())
                document.cookie = "other_lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
                marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
                getAddress(event.latLng);
                var cookie_val = ('other_lat_lng', event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng())
                document.cookie = "other_lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
            });
        }
        var a_message = "<%= I18n.t 'map_other' %>"

        var geocoder;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        function getAddress(latLng) {
            geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
                function(results, status) {
                    if(status = google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if(results[0]) {
                            document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("address").value = a_message;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("address").value = status;
                    }
                });
        }


    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());
```

```css
#map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><input type="text" id="address" size="30"><br><input type="text" id="lat" size="10"><input type="text" id="lng" size="10">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was asked before. [Answer is taken from stackoverflow question 13525749](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525749/google-maps-is-grey)

I had an issue like that and `resize` solved it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Joyce, where exactly should I place this code?

Comment: For example, `<html><body><!-- your map here --></body> <!-- insert here --></html>`